# How can I be alerted if my recursion decides to start skipping loops?

Tags: vb.net, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a nested For / Next recursion at the heart of a web app I am trying to develop. When I programmed it, I verified its output on an example that nested 3-5 levels and thought all was well.

Lately, I decided to verify an entry in the result set that was nested 12 to 15 levels deep. The resulting percentage was incorrect because some progeny were not recursed.

Because my result set can take so long to run (8-13 hours for the more indepth queries) and I could run the same test on a subset (~150,000 records) of the records in the full database table (~1,200,000 records), I trialled it against the smaller table.

Low and behold it appears to work perfectly. A search that was returning ~56,000 records, returned ~126,000 records (meaning it was previously skipping out a lot of recursions). I verified random sample results to be correct.

Comparing result sets from the same query done on the two database tables, it seems that the missed recursions start to show up with some (not all) of the records that are nested beyond 12 levels deep.

The troubling thing for me is that I need to know when my result set is suspect without having to search the result set for dropped nesting.

Here is the code for the recursive sub:

```
' lookup table for up to 63 generations '
Dim percentage() As Double = {100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125, ect. . .}

' DataTable to display results of looping through the db '
Dim t As DataTable
Dim c As DataColumn
Dim r As DataRow
' columns are: id, name, dad, mom, gender, year born, trait, percentage '

Private Sub GetPct(ByRef progeny As List(Of Int32), ByRef gender As List(Of String), ByVal generations As Int16, ByVal count As Int16)
    Dim nxtGeneration As Int16 = generations + 1
    Dim nxtPercentage As Double = percentage(nxtGeneration)
    For i As Int16 = 0 To count
        Dim dbConn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim j As Int16 = -1
        Dim prog As New List(Of Int32)
        Dim gndr As New List(Of String)
        If gender(i) = "M" Then
            Dim dreader As SqlDataReader
            Dim dgetComm As New SqlCommand("d_get", dbConn)
            dgetComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            dgetComm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
            dgetComm.Parameters("@id").Value = prog(i)
            Using dbConn
                Try
                    dbConn.Open()
                    dreader = dgetComm.ExecuteReader()
                    If dreader.HasRows = True Then
                        While dreader.Read()
                            j += 1
                            Dim updated As DataRow = t.Rows.Find(dreader(0))
                            If updated Is Nothing Then
                                t.BeginLoadData()
                                r = t.NewRow()
                                r(0) = dreader(0)
                                r(1) = dreader(1)
                                r(2) = dreader(2)
                                r(3) = dreader(3)
                                r(4) = dreader(4)
                                r(5) = dreader(5)
                                r(6) = dreader(6)
                                r(7) = nxtPercentage
                                t.Rows.Add(r)
                                t.EndLoadData()
                                prg.Add(dreader(0))
                                gnd.Add(dreader(4))
                            Else
                                prg.Add(dreader(0))
                                gnd.Add(dreader(4))
                                updated(7) += nxtPercentage
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                    dgetComm.Dispose()
                    dgetComm = Nothing
                    dreader.Close()
                    dreader = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
        ' modify when going live '
                    lblDetails.Text &= "Error loading to table with get of dam" & Err.Description
                End Try
            End Using
            GetPct(prg, gnd, nxtG, j)
        Else
            Dim sreader As SqlDataReader
            Dim sgetComm As New SqlCommand("s_get", dbConn)
            sgetComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sgetComm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
            sgetComm.Parameters("@id").Value = prog(i)
            Using dbConn
                Try
                    dbConn.Open()
                    sreader = sgetComm.ExecuteReader()
                    If sreader.HasRows = True Then
                        While sreader.Read()
                            j += 1
                            Dim updated As DataRow = t.Rows.Find(srdr(0))
                            If updated Is Nothing Then
                                t.BeginLoadData()
                                r = t.NewRow()
                                r(0) = sreader(0)
                                r(1) = sreader(1)
                                r(2) = sreader(2)
                                r(3) = sreader(3)
                                r(4) = sreader(4)
                                r(5) = sreader(5)
                                r(6) = sreader(6)
                                r(7) = nxtPercentage
                                t.Rows.Add(r)
                                t.EndLoadData()
                                prg.Add(sreader(0))
                                gnd.Add(sreader(4))
                            Else
                                prg.Add(sreader(0))
                                gnd.Add(sreader(4))
                                updated(7) += nxtPercentage
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                    sgetComm.Dispose()
                    sgetComm = Nothing
                    sreader.Close()
                    sreader = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
        ' modify when going live'
                    lblDetails.Text &= "Error loading to table with get of sire" & Err.Description
                End Try
            End Using
            GetPct(prg, gnd, nxtG, j)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a few things to say, though nothing directly helping you to solve this problem. Anyway. First of all, can you please format your text a little bit, it is very hard, it even hurts to read. Please try avoiding excessive, not important information. Second of all, your code looks like a mess. Use variable names that are clear (what are "t", "gnd", "gdnr", ...), the next guy probably will think "wtX" does this all mean. And at last, try avoiding duplicate code, which you certainly have.

Comment: Hopefully this is clearer. : )

Comment: To echo @Styxxy, you can do this in half the code you have posted, as 99% of your code is the same between male and female (or appears to be).  As far as catching a bad result set, you'd need to write the logic to check the results after you get them at each level, and then either exit the run with an error message or log the error and level somewhere and then continue the processing.

Comment: Have you considered letting SQL Server do the recursion via a Common Table Expression (CTE)?

Comment: Tim - Thanks for looking this over. Would shortening the code, speed up the procedure? Also, how do you identify a "bad" result set? Either the code checks each descendant returned from the db query or it opts out. I have no idea why it is opting out of processing each descendant just because of the size of my database table.

Comment: HABO - Thanks for your recommendation. Would CTE help my recursion go faster?

Comment: HABO - I guess I am a little suspicious of the possible limitations of sql server 2008 R2 express.

Comment: Styxxy - Thanks for your comment, I hope it helps clarify the problem if you get another chance to review this.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks for looking this over. Would shortening the code, speed up the procedure? Also, how do you identify a "bad" result set? Either the code checks each descendant returned from the db query or it opts out. I have no idea why it is opting out of processing each descendant just because of the size of my database table.

Comment: @HABO - Thanks for your recommendation. Would CTE help my recursion go faster? I guess I am a little suspicious of the possible limitations of sql server 2008 R2 express.

Comment: @Styxxy - Thanks for your comment, I hope it helps clarify the problem if you get another chance to review this.

Comment: It would save a round trip to the database for each descendant. I'd expect it to be considerably faster. And it can calculate the percentages as it goes. You should be able to test a CTE fairly easily (assuming that `d_get` doesn't contain any magic) and see how it performs.

Comment: @user3105510 - No, shortening the code wouldn't give a noticeable speed increase, it'd just make it a *lot* easier to read and maintain.  HABO is right - this kind of heavy processing should be done on the SQL side, as that is what SQL excels at, not on the client side.

Comment: Tim and @HABO - I will pursue CTE and see how it compares. d_get and s_get simply select the progeny of any given parent (d_get searches the mothers, s_get the fathers). Will going to a CTE solution also overcome the issue of progeny going awol on me?